# Cross-Origin Request issue check it

Tags: spring-boot

When hit my SpringBoot Backed using FireFox
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:7070/auth/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
but when i hit my SppringBoot Backend using chrome it perfectly fine solve this issue

Please Give me the solution